# How to find third point of triangle with specific area?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vector-spaces

If $A = (3, 5)$ and $B = (11, 11)$ are fixed points, find the point(s)
$P$ on the $x$-axis such that the area of the triangle $ABP$ equals $30$.

I feel that somehow idea of cross product is involved, but I don't know how.

$\frac{A\times B}{2}$ is area of triangle between vectors $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Find the length of $AB=\sqrt{(11-3)^2+(11-5)^2}$. Then draw two lines parallel to $AB$ and at distance $2\times 30/AB$ from the line $AB$. Any point on those lines is a solution. Since, to determine a line it is enough to find two points on it, you can just find points on the $X$ and on the $Y$ axis. There should be two points on each and are easy to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you can use cross product...

you can say $A = \frac 12 |(3,11,x)\times (5,11,0)| = 30$

or you can say:

$A = \frac 12 |(3-x, 5)\times(11-x,11)| = 30$

The shoelace algorithm is essentially the first one.

$\begin{array} {}
3&5\\11&11\\x&0\end{array}$

$A = \frac 12 |(3\cdot 11 +11\cdot 0 + x\cdot 5 - 5\cdot 11 - 11\cdot x - 0\cdot 3)| =30\\
|22  + 6x| = 60\\
x = \frac {38}{6}\\
x = -\frac {82}{6}$

Comment: @amd thanks, better now.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

The area of a triangle with vertices $(x_A,y_A)$, $(x_B,y_B)$ and $(x_C,y_C)$ is given by
$$\frac12\left|\det\begin{pmatrix}x_A&x_B&x_C\\y_A&y_B&y_C\\1&1&1\end{pmatrix}\right|$$

Then, if $(x_C,y_C)$ lies oh the $x$ axis, $y_C=0$ and then we are looking for those $x_C$ such that
$$\frac12\left|\det\begin{pmatrix}3&11&x_C\\5&11&0\\1&1&1\end{pmatrix}\right|=30$$